# Tomcat keeps asking for password and username

Tags: java, xml, apache, tomcat

Hi I am not sure I am trying to connect to apache server, this is a class I am taking, but now after I removed the code and restored it back to default, it keeps asking for the password now.

This is what I have in my tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
<user username="ide" password="EiWnNlBG" roles="manager-script,admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

also this is in tools ---> server ---> pass and user name.

and error i get in output

```
Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username and password with the "manager-script" role in the Tomcat customizer in the Server Manager.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Only thing I changed was tomcat-users.xml  and web.xml  but I restored everything back to normal and still asking for username and password.

Comment: See here: http://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/02/installing-tomcat-7-and-configuring-as-server-in-netbeans/

Comment: How are you building and deploying? Using an ANT script? Maybe you haven't updated the credentials in you deployment script. What IDE are you using? Also are there multiple tomcats installed? maybe you are pointing to the wrong tomcat or not pointing to the tomcat at all? I suggest step back and check everything again.

Answer (score 1):

This drove me nuts for ages. I jumped through all the hoops of modifying XML files to no avail. Driven to the point of distraction I killed all Apache/Tomcat processes and services but still http://localhost:8080 kept asking me for a username and password. So I figured something else must be using port 8080. But what? Time to go old school, to go back to CMD (remembering to run CMD as administrator).

> netstat -aon | findstr 8080
>
> TCP     0.0.0.0:8080     0.0.0.0:0     LISTENING     3472
>     TCP       [::]:8080        [::]:0        LISTENING     3472

So, process id 3472 is using the port. But what is process id 3472?

> tasklist | findstr 3472
>
> TNSLSNR.EXE             3472 Services     0    13,256 K

So, a quick Google search for TNSLSNR reveals that it's an Oracle listener. Do I need it right now. No. So I killed it.

> taskkill /F /PID 3472
>
> SUCCESS: The process with PID 3472 has been terminated.

Yay! Now free of interference from non Apache/Tomcat processes and/or services I can concentrate on getting the Apache config right.

Answer (score 1):

For myself, I had this issue because I was using a special character & in my password. Make sure to escape them or replace with something else.

Comment: For me it was the "!" character